# Use Javascript string as selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables, html

I have in Javascript:

```
 for ( i=0; i < parseInt(ids); i++){
   var vst = '#'+String(img_arr[i]);
   var dst = '#'+String(div_arr[i]);
  }
```

How can I continue in jQuery like:

```
    $(function() {
     $(vst).'click': function() {
      ....
     }
    }
```

Comment: $(vst).click(function() { });

Comment: `$(vst).'click': function() {` is just completely wrong syntax. I recommend to make yourself familiar with the JavaScript syntax first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide and reading a jQuery tutorial probably helps as well: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, like this instead

```
 $(function() {
     $(vst).click(function() {
         ....
     });
 });
```

There are other ways depending on your version of `jquery` library

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will actually wait 5 minutes to accept the answer although it's about 5 AM already )

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, but other than that you will have no problem with that. To specify a click:

```
 $(function() {
      for ( i=0; i < parseInt(ids); i++){
          var vst = '#'+String(img_arr[i]);
          var dst = '#'+String(div_arr[i]);

          $(vst).click(function (evt) {
                ...
          });
      }
 })
```

Note that since `vst` is changing in the loop, your event code should also be placed in the loop.

EDIT: Assuming you want the same thing to happen for each image and each div, you could also do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    function imgEventSpec($evt) {
        // image clicked.
    }

    function divEventSpec($evt) {
        // div clicked.
    }

    for (var idx = 0; idx < img_arr.length && idx < div_arr.length; idx ++) {
        $("#" + img_arr[idx]).click(imgEventSpec);
        $("#" + div_arr[idx]).click(divEventSpec);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding to this, your vst must need to be an object which allow you to click on it, and you assign a class or id to the object in order to trigger the function and runs the for...loop

correct me if I am wrong, cause this is what I get from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 $(vst).click(function() {
  ....
 }
})
```

You can use any string as element selector param for jQuery.

Read the docs for more information.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a String in a variable to the `$()` just the way you want to do it.

For example you can do:

```
var id = 'banner';
var sel = '#'+id;
$(sel).doSomething(); //will select '#banner'
```

What's wrong is the syntax you are using when binding the click handler. This would usually work like:

```
$(sel).click(function(){
//here goes what you want to do in the handler
});
```

See the docs for **[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)**

Comment: Or you could be a little briefer - `$("#" + id).click(function() {})`

Comment: @RemarkLima I'm just trying to "get the message across", won't be winning any performance awards though....

Comment: of course :) Hence the upvote! Just trying to keep the good content on SO, with more detail for those that need it

Comment: Accidentally downvoted, apparently, and now I can't undo it (it says it's locked).  Sorry!!!